# How to install a symlink within an rpm spec file

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I've read through several other questions related to this issue, and I can't find a direct answer to my issue. I have to install several symlinks to /etc that point to files I am installing in /opt/myapp, so I need my files to look like this:

/etc/sysconfig/myapp -> /opt/myapp/etc/sysconfig/myapp

Right now my spec file looks like this:

```
%install
ln -sf %{buildroot}/etc/sysconfig/myapp /opt/myapp/etc/sysconfig/myapp

%files
%attr(0644, root, root) "/etc/sysconfig/myapp"
%dir %attr(0755, root, root) "/opt/myapp/etc/sysconfig"
%config(noreplace) %attr(0644, root, root) "/opt/myapp/etc/sysconfig/myapp"
```

When I run `rpmbuild`, I get this:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/opt/myapp/etc/sysconfig/myapp': No such file or directory
```

I know this directory does not exist. It gets installed by the `%files` section, so how do I avoid this error here?

Answer (score 1):

[`ln` takes the *target* first](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html), so it should be `ln -sf /opt/myapp/etc/sysconfig/myapp %{buildroot}/etc/sysconfig/myapp`

- `-s` to make it a symlink
- `-f` because `/opt/myapp/etc/sysconfig/myapp` doesn't need to exist on the build system